Expectation of minimums over a variable set
Jensen's inequality implies that $\mathbb{E}[\min_{k∈[N]}X_k]≤\min_{k∈[N]} \mathbb{E}[X_k]$ for random variables $X_k$'s.
Can we say something if the set over which we take the minimum is also a random variable, instead of the fixed indices in $[N]$?
More specifically, suppose we have real-valued variables $X_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$. Each variable $X_i=X_i(T)$ is a function of the random variable $T$.
The set $S=S(T)$ contains indices of the elements $X_i$, and which indices it contains also depends on $T$. The size $|S|$ is always fixed, so does not depend on $T$ (perhaps this is not important).
Does the following inequality hold?
$$\mathbb{E}_T[\min_{k∈S(T)}X_k(T)]≤\mathbb{E}_T\big[\min_{k∈S(T)} \mathbb{E}_T[X_k(T)]\big]$$
